# How do I address root in pytorches' ImageFolder

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, pytorch-dataloader

I'm working on making a neural net on aws sagemaker. I am trying to classify images of dog breeds with multiple images in multiple folders with each folder being named a category of dog. How do I set up a train_data variable using ImageFolder. I have tried putting "dogImages/train", using the os.environment channels, and s3, but it keeps saying that the directory does not exist.

Logs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train_model.py", line 251, in 
main(args)
File "train_model.py", line 170, in main
train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root= "dogImages/train", transform=TRANSFORM_IMG)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 256, in **init**
is_valid_file=is_valid_file)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 126, in **init**
classes, class_to_idx = self._find_classes(self.root)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 164, in _find_classes
classes = [d.name for d in os.scandir(dir) if d.is_dir()]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dogImages/train'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this SageMaker PyTorch [example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/prep_data/image_data_guide/04c_pytorch_training.ipynb) - it uses torchvison.datasets.ImageFolder